Add a cell above the first column in Pandas dataframe
I have a dataframe, say df:
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
        "Age": [25, 30, 35],
        "City": ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago"]
    })
df




Name
Age
City




Alice
25
New York


Bob
30
Los Angeles


Charlie
35
Chicago



I want to add a cell on top of the first column (Name) with cell color - Yellow, something like - 
I want Name, Age and City to remain as columns.
I have tried it, but the approach isn't good, but I know there might be some other better way. My code below:
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
        "Age": [25, 30, 35],
        "City": ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago"]
    })
# change the column name for temporary basis
df.columns = ['INPUT', 'a', 'b']

# create a new row
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'INPUT': ['Name'], 'a': ['Age'], 'b':['City']})
# concat the newly created row with the existing dataframe df
df = pd.concat([new_row, df]).reset_index(drop=True)

# rename the column, keep only the 'INPUT'
df.columns = ['INPUT', '', '']
df


You could proceed in two steps. First write the INPUT, then write your DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
        'Age': [25, 30, 35],
        'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago'],
    }
)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

(
    pd.DataFrame([['INPUT']])
    .style.map(lambda x: 'background-color: yellow')
    .set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
    .to_excel(writer, header=False, index=False)
)

df.to_excel(writer, startrow=1, index=False)

writer.close()

Output:


I'm fairly sure that OP isn't asking for Excel output, but a single DataFrame object that would look similar to his Excel screenshot.

So, I don't believe that what you are asking for is possible within a DataFrame. At least, not as they are.
You're going to run into two issues:

Displaying - DataFrames are a way for you to structure information, not display it. You can't "set" a specific cell to a specific colour, as the DataFrame object doesn't have a way of storing display information. Instead, you would need whatever method reads and displays the DataFrame to know to display specific cell as Yellow.

Data Structure - DataFrames have rows and columns. If you would like ['Name', 'Age', 'City'] as your column headers, then they will be at the top. If you would like something else as your column headers, then those will be at the top.


To address the first issue, the only way I can think of to assign display information to an object while keeping DataFrame functionality is to create a Class which either inherits or interfaces with the DataFrame class, then implements some way to display your new class that includes this colour.
To address the second issue, you have a few options:

Create a class that inherits or interfaces with the DataFrame class, which has an attribute for a main header and some method to display your class objects with the main header above the column headers.
Run with your existing solution, (though I would recommend adding an index column, with the index for your ['Name', 'Age', 'City'] row as something like "Headers").
Structure your DataFrame in an Excel-esque way with Rows 1-n and Columns A-Z. Then you can set the value of any "cell" as you would like, with "INPUT" in your first row, and your other headers in the second row. Note that there's not really a point in using a DataFrame at that point.


Patrick vD - Thanks for your suggestion, yes u were correct, I need something with dataframe first, which I might or might not export it to excel (that is not important I mean export in excel). So tbh!! I need the output in that format and then I will send that output in someones's  e-mail (ignore the email part, its off-topic here). You can also skip the colouring part, but would it be possible to add a cell above the first column without using excel thing?

@maven as defined, there is no "Above the first column". To give you an excel counterpart, it's like asking me to store a value above the column headers ('A', 'B', 'C', .... 'ZZA', 'ZZB', ...).
Your columns headers will always be the top, unless you make them a row (and make something else the column header) then you can have another row above them.
At most, you could play around with setting df.index.name and/or df.columns.name and see if that is satisfactory.

try this:
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'your_file_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=1)
    workbook = writer.book
    title_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFFF00', 'align': 'center'})
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'INPUT', title_format)

